# update mysqli only if datetime is null

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have an assignment. system should update the column datetime only if it is null.

I have this query

```
update posts set name = '$name', pubdate = case when pubdate is null 
then now()
else pubdate end 
where id = '$postid'
```

is this the correct way to do this? any other better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine.  I might write this more concisely as:

```
update posts
    set name = '$name',
        pubdate = coalesce(pubdate, now())
    where id = '$postid';
```

Notes:

- If the ids are numeric, don't put the value in single quotes.
- More importantly, `$name` and `$postid` should be parameters to the query, rather than directly inserted into the query string.